# Microsoft Office store app approved but not visible

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, office-store

I can see that my Outlook add-in is approved in the developer dashboard, and I also received an email 14 days ago from Microsoft saying that it was approved. But I can't find the add-in in the Office store. The release date was set to a date 30 days ago.

Is there something more that I need to do for the add-in to become available in the store?

Comment: Your add-in should have been published to, and visible on AppSource shortly after approval, assuming the release date was not set to the future. Can you share the add-in title?

Comment: I can find the add-in in AppSource (https://appsource.microsoft.com/da-dk/product/office/WA104381837?tab=Overview), but I can't find it when I search for add-ins from Outlook (both web and desktop version).

Comment: I've opened a ticket with our engineering team to investigate this issue.

Comment: Our engineering team have resolved this issue and the add-in is available when searched in both the Outlook client and Outlook on the web. Apologies for the inconvenience caused.

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to language restrictions.
For example, if you specify that your add-in is available in French but your Office365 is in English, then the french add-in is not displayed in the store.

Try to switch your Office 365 in the same language as your add-in.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The add-in is available in English, and I have tried to set the Outlook language to both English (US) and English (UK), but still no add-in in the store.